# How can I get search results with 3 letters in my searchkeyword?

Tags: search-results

I am using SharePoint 2013 and have created my custom search result page. On this search result page I have changed the search query. It looks now like this:

[image]

When I search on a whole word like "shoes", "soccer", "house" it give me results. But when I enter only 2 or 3 letters it dont give me results back. I try for example "sho", "soc", "ous". Is it possible to configure my SharePoint search that it is possible to get also results with small search keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is no "full-word" hits on the fragments of words you are searching on. Try applying the wildcard (*) after the search query.

```
sho*
```

You should now get results. So in your example above, add an asterix after

```
{SearchBoxQuery}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I have added also an asterix before. This is my query now: Path:{SiteCollection.URL}   ContentTypeId:0x0100BA09E7695455FC4B8D3716A128EF73B3*  Artikelen:*{SearchBoxQuery}*

Comment: Hmm the asterix before shouldn't really do anything :) SharePoint doesn't support suffix-matching: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89055/how-can-i-get-suffix-matching-in-a-search-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: And what about letters in the middle of a word?

Comment: Same there, it is prefix-matching only (like hell*, not *ello, not he*lo)