# Pattern matching with question mark wildcards in SharePoint 2013 FQL

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint, wildcard-search

According to the book [70-489 Study Guide - Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions](https://www.amazon.de/70-489-Study-Guide-Developing-SharePoint/dp/1493583611/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1490946788&sr=8-1&keywords=70-489) (Chapter: "Building FQL Queries") it is still possible to use the question mark wildcard in SP 2013 FQL search requests. I tested it, and it isn't working like described.

### Prerequisites

Lets say I have the following four documents that are crawled and can be found using the default search:

```
PROJ-3122-DEV.pdf    
PROJ-3122-HELP.pdf  
PROJ-5442-DEV.pdf   
PROJECT_DEVELOPMENT.pdf
```

As described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj163973.aspx), I created a custom result source to work with FQL.
To test my queries, I'm using the [SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com).

### Testing

I need a search request that only returns documents matching the pattern *PROJ-####-DEV.pdf*

Here are the queries I tried with my expectations and the real results

---

**Title:PROJ**

Expected

```
PROJ-3122-DEV.pdf    
PROJ-3122-HELP.pdf  
PROJ-5442-DEV.pdf   
PROJECT_DEVELOPMENT.pdf
```

Final

```
PROJ-3122-DEV.pdf    
PROJ-3122-HELP.pdf  
PROJ-5442-DEV.pdf
```

---

**Title:PROJ***

Expected and final results are the same

```
PROJ-3122-DEV.pdf    
PROJ-3122-HELP.pdf  
PROJ-5442-DEV.pdf   
PROJECT_DEVELOPMENT.pdf
```

---

**Title:PROJ*DEV**

**Title:PROJ-*-DEV**

**Title:PROJ-????-DEV**

Expected

```
PROJ-3122-DEV.pdf  
PROJ-5442-DEV.pdf
```

Final

```
The query returned zero items
```

---

### Remarks

As you can see, the search results are often times unexpected. Is there a way to get a simple pattern matching using question marks? 
As far as I know, the asterisk is used for zero or more characters including spaces, whereas the question mark is used exactly for one character. Maybe the problem with asterisks stems from the fact, [that they can only be used for prefix searches](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89055/how-can-i-get-suffix-matching-in-a-search-in-sharepoint-2013); that would explain why **Title:PROJ*DEV** and **Title:PROJ*-*DEV** don't return results.
So to match the four digits in the document title I assumed searching for **PROJ-????-DEV** would be the right way.

Additionally I checked the request-URL which contained encoded questionmarks (*%3f*); I replaced them with real questionmarks but the result was the same.

Any help regarding the topic and how to match that specific pattern would be really appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, the study book is wrong. ? is not supported. Only post-fix *, meaning at the end of a term. Not at the start, not in the middle. Only at the end.

Comment: And using a `-` negates the terms that follow.