# Is there a way to alter search term to include terms similar to the one entered?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, sharepoint-search

I have a document library within which users run a search. If the users enter a number (ex. 881765) the results should show files containing "R881765" or "F;881765" or "|2881765"

Basically appending 5 or so different strings to the beginning of {subjectTerms} to search every combination.

Comment: Are you using Community build Search webpart on SPO or using OOB MS Search or using CSOM/REST based search query?

Comment: I am using OOB MS Search on SPO. The default search that comes with the "Collaboration Site" Template.

Comment: Yes it is doable but as of now SPO is limited on search functionality. Follow the link to more about SPO Modern vs Classic Search limitations. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search

Comment: If you can use community based search web part and target to a specific result type, you can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not support suffix wildcard search, it only support for prefix matching.

When you use words in a free-text KQL query, Search in SharePoint returns results based on exact matches of your words with the terms stored in the full-text index. You can use just a part of a word, from the beginning of the word, by using the wildcard operator (*) to enable prefix matching. In prefix matching, Search in SharePoint matches results with terms that contain the word followed by zero or more characters.

eg:Federated Searc*

Similar issue post for your reference:

[How can I get suffix matching in a search in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89055/how-can-i-get-suffix-matching-in-a-search-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: It is possible using query transform but in SPO OOB search, right now we dont have concept of using a specific result source, otherwise for classic SP, configure a result source with query transform.

Comment: Also, you are also correct for wild card part, there is no wild card prefix matching option in SPO. But as the requirement listed they need to append a finite set of words to the query which is possible.